# Git clone inside of newly created container - problem with known_hosts

Tags: docker, dockerfile, ssh-keys, known-hosts

I would like to ask how to solve the problem that when I try to `git clone ...`  in the container it will fail due to that the server is not in known_hosts. Is there way how to force "yes" in:

```
The authenticity of host '192.168.0.136 (192.168.0.136)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:tZiiWJJYFdtTmjjk3kunA4dU3wI2WXPI/1O0EsMtIjk.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])?
```

I have tried `yes | git clone ...` but it is not working

Right now I am doing it this way:

`echo "github.com,140.82.121.3 ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEAq2A7hRGmdnm9tUDbO9IDSwBK6TbQa+PXYPCPy6rbTrTtw7PHkccKrpp0yVhp5HdEIcKr6pLlVDBfOLX9QUsyCOV0wzfjIJNlGEYsdlLJizHhbn2mUjvSAHQqZETYP81eFzLQNnPHt4EVVUh7VfDESU84KezmD5QlWpXLmvU31/yMf+Se8xhHTvKSCZIFImWwoG6mbUoWf9nzpIoaSjB+weqqUUmpaaasXVal72J+UX2B+2RPW3RcT0eOzQgqlJL3RKrTJvdsjE3JEAvGq3lGHSZXy28G3skua2SmVi/w4yCE6gbODqnTWlg7+wC604ydGXA8VJiS5ap43JXiUFFAaQ==" >> /root/.ssh/known_hosts \`

But the first approach would look better than having this in Dockerfile

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it in below way

```sh
ssh-keyscan github.com >> /root/.ssh/known_hosts
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the fingerprint as a new file and create a volume that maps this file, before the container starts.

1. Get the fingerprint

```
ssh-keyscan github.com >> [MY_DOCKER_PROJECT]/.ssh/known_hosts
```

2. Add to docker-compose.yml:

```
    volumes:
      - ./ssh/known_hosts:/root/.ssh/known_hosts
```